# how to remove #shadow-root (user-agent) from html

Tags: html, dom

What is #shadow-root (user-agent)? how to remove it from text boxes?

**In Detail**
This is my code:

```
<input type="text" name="pincode" class="form-control frm_pincode" value="" />
```

But when I inspect it I see like

```
<input type="text" name="pincode" class="form-control frm_pincode" value="">
  #shadow-root (user-agent)
  <div id="inner-editor"></div>
</input>
```

Comment: are you using specific library for text editors ? such as inymce or ckeditor

Comment: I've faced a similar issue and fixed by adding css for `shadow content` like in this case `#inner-editor`

Comment: That's browser rendered `shadow dom`, you can not change it directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially it encapsulates code, making it more manageable.  It's not necessarily something you're going to want to remove without making the functionality of the code you did generate unusable.

The following is code is hidden from you by the library you're using so you don't have to worry about coding certain objects.  Chrome allows you to see where those #shadow Doms are located in the code.

```
  #shadow-root (user-agent)
  <div id="inner-editor"></div>
```

Check out this explanation from the link below:

> "In a nutshell Shadow DOM is a new part of the HTML spec which allows
>   developers to encapsulate their HTML markup, CSS styles and
>   JavaScript. Shadow DOM, along with a few other technologies which
>   we’ll cover later, gives developers the ability to build their own 1st
>   class tags and APIs just like the  or  tag.
>   Collectively, these new tags and APIs are referred to as Web
>   Components."

The link below was key in helping understanding shadow DOM:
http://robdodson.me/blog/2013/08/26/shadow-dom-introduction/

This makes use of the shadow DOM to make creating custom tags possible:
https://www.polymer-project.org/

Finally, there's also an option under Chrome Dev Tools Options to "Show user agent shadow DOM"

Comment: That option doesn't work in Google Chrome 57.0.2987.133 on Windows 10 - for locally hosted pages it always shows, no matter whether it's on or off.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Does this appear to be the case only in localhost?  I'll do some digging to see if this is a feature or bug.  I also see this on Chrome  57.0.2987.133 on macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: It also shows for google.nl and stackoverflow.com, so anything that's not `file://` seems to be affected.

Comment: You might try disabling your extensions to see if any of those are the culprit.