# Xampp automaticly adds #shadow-root to my html document

Tags: google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

So I created a clean install of xampp because my old one became pretty messy, now When I created a new index file, even when empty my browser (chrome 38) seems to add this:

```
#shadow-root
<shadow></shadow>
```

What does it do, or how can I remove this?

**edit:** this only appears to be happening on Chrome 38, not on Firefox or IE

Comment: You can remove it by hitting F12 for Chrome Dev Tools and in the gear shaped `settings` icon, you can uncheck `Show user agent shadow DOM` checkbox. Read an introduction to `Shadow DOM` [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-shadow-dom--net-34966).

Comment: That setting isn't checked. Nor does it change if I check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove #shadow-root (user-agent) from html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891549/how-to-remove-shadow-root-user-agent-from-html)

Answer (score 0):

Same with Google Chrome 57.0.2987.133 on Windows 10 in XAMPP 5.6.30 and [UwAmp](http://www.uwamp.com) 1.3.0.

A blank html file opened via `file://` does have expected empty source.

I'd try [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [Hiawatha](https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/), though even the latter shows shadow mess in Chrome's inspector, so it's probably a Chrome issue. Other Blink (still Webkit on iOS) browsers like [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org) probably do it as well, so try [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/products/).